Convert timestamp to new format using SED
I have a giant .md file with a series of entries that represent the date like so:
[2024/06/10 10:03 PM]

However, I need to alter all of these so they now appear like so:
20240610.

Thinking through this problem, I need to:

Remove all the /, but only the ones within the [square brackets]
Remove the timestamps, like 10:03 PM.
Add a period at the end of the YYYMMDD.

There is generally something else on these date lines that functions as a title, for example:
[2024/06/10 10:03 PM] Title of Some Sort.

Ideas?

What do the actual lines look like? Is that the only thing on each line? Is it at least the first characters? Or can the date appear anywhere? Can you have anything else in square brackets? Please [edit] the question and give a more complete example.

Good question. There is usually something on the line after the brackets: [2024/06/12 10:56 AM] Title of Some Kind.

So we can safely assume that the pattern you want is always and exclusively the beginning of the line? So we can, for instance, just remove exactly the first 2 slashes?

And what should the output be? Should we remove the rest of the line or keep it? Please give an example with a few lines and the output you expect of them.

Assuming a sed implementation with support for -E for extended regexps (only standard since the 2024 edition of POSIX).
d='[0123456789]'
sed -E "s|\[($d{4})/($d$d)/($d$d) $d$d:$d$d [AP]M\]|\1\2\3.|g" file.md

Or perl (as usual more portable, possibly more efficient, more reliable in the face of non-text, shorter).
perl -pe 's|\[(\d{4})/(\d\d)/(\d\d) \d\d:\d\d [AP]M\]|$1$2$3.|g' file.md

Add a -i option to edit the file in place (some sed implementations have copied that -i from perl but in incompatible fashion between themselves).

Are there locales where [0-9] includes more than 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9?

@glennjackman, in the case of perl it's always 0123456789, with sed YMMV depending on locale but also system, libc, or other library supplying the regexp engine and implementations, and versions thereof. But yes, I've seen many including en_US ones (for instance, you could argue that ² should be somewhere inbetween 1 and 3 like 2).

This seems to work: sed -E 's/[([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2}) [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} (AM|PM)]/\1\2\3./g' "$input_file" > temp_file.md

A script like the following does what you want, assuming there's nothing else on the line.
# Remove square brackets and convert spaces to slashes
dateonly=$(echo "[2024/06/10 10:03 PM]" | tr -d ][ |tr ' ' /)

# Get the year, month and day parts
y=$(echo $dateonly|cut -d/ -f1)
m=$(echo $dateonly|cut -d/ -f2)
d=$(echo $dateonly|cut -d/ -f3)

# Reformat the date as required
newdate=${y}${m}${d}.
# (The curly braces could be omitted, but (I think) make the intention more clear.)

# Test
echo $newdate
20240610.


Assuming you want to leave the rest of the line unchanged but remove all cases of a [ at the beginning of a line followed by three sets of numbers, separated by a slash and everything else until the first ], you can do:
$ perl -pe 's|^\[(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)[^]]+\]|$1$2$3.|' file 
20240610. Title of Some Sort.

The regular expression looks for a [ at the beginning of the line (^\[) followed by exactly three sets of one or more digits separated by / ((\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)) and then one or more non-] characters ([^]]) until the first ] (\]). Since the numbers (\d+) are in parentheses, this means they are captured and can be referred to as $n on the right hand side of the substitution operator, meaning that the first captured group will be $1, the second $2 and so on. So this substitution will replace the entire matched pattern with just $1$2$3, i.e. the digits of the date, and a full stop.
Whether or not this is specific enough for your real data will depend on what the real data are.
